# Fitting Logistic Regression Model for my data

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I want a plot a similar graph copied from the publication. The graph is % Survival (on y-axis) and time (on x-axis)

My Objective Graph

[image]

Here is my data and script:

```
dat <- read.table(text= "G Time Survival 
1 0 93
1 3 90
1 9 2
1 15 1
1 20 0
1 25 0
1 30 1
1 35 0
1 40 0
1 45 0
1 55 0
1 65 0
2 0 100
2 3 100
2 9 100
2 15 98
2 20 99
2 25 98
2 30 97
2 35 97
2 40 95
2 45 76
2 55 72
2 65 66
3 0 97
3 3 94
3 9 80
3 15 26
3 20 20
3 25 0
3 30 0
3 35 0
3 40 1
3 45 0
3 55 0
3 65 0
4 0 94
4 3 81
4 9 35
4 15 19
4 20 5
4 25 2
4 30 0
4 35 0
4 40 0
4 45 1
4 55 0
4 65 0
5 0 96
5 3 96
5 9 97
5 15 96
5 20 93
5 25 95
5 30 89
5 35 99
5 40 92
5 45 87
5 55 63
5 65 63
6 0 95
6 3 94
6 9 99
6 15 92
6 20 81
6 25 80
6 30 64
6 35 41
6 40 48
6 45 12
6 55 22
6 65 19
7 0 97
7 3 96
7 9 92
7 15 92
7 20 94
7 25 79
7 30 74
7 35 56
7 40 50
7 45 20
7 55 2
7 65 0
8 0 95
8 3 84
8 9 13
8 15 10
8 20 3
8 25 6
8 30 7
8 35 4
8 40 0
8 45 0
8 55 0
8 65 0", header = TRUE)
```

```
attach(dat)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=dat) + 
      geom_point(mapping=aes(x=Time,y=Survival)) + 
      facet_wrap(~ G, nrow=2)

ggplot(data=dat) + 
      geom_point(mapping=aes(x=Time,y=Survival)) + 
      geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x=Time,y=Survival),method="glm", family = binomial, se = FALSE, fill=NA) + 
      facet_wrap(~ G, nrow=2)
```

This results in the following graph:

[image]

So, Friends, please help me to fit the logistic regression model like the one in the first picture.

Comment: You data sample gives percentage survival by time. Do you have the underlying data on the individuals that your summary data were derived from? If so, you should model those data using an appropriate survival model. The survival model will give you a survival curve that you can plot.

Comment: Might be best to think about how to model your data before plotting it; are you sure you should be using logistic regression? One possible alternative, is to use the  logistic function, where parameters are estimated using nls. So change the smooth to `geom_smooth(method="nls", formula = y ~ 100 / (1 + exp(-a* (x - b))),
 se = FALSE, fill=NA, method.args=list(start = c(a=-0.05, b=50)))`. To see the parameters you can model outside of the figure:  `library(nlme) ;
m = nlsList(Survival ~ 100 / (1 + exp(-a* (Time - b)))|G,  data = dat, start = c(a=-0.05, b=50), na.action=na.omit) ; coef(m)`

Comment: Dear Friend, thank you very much for the answer. Yes data from each time point is the mean of two replication. I have the underlying data. But I want to use the logistic function, so I will try to use the code hereby and get back to you, if i need any help. So kind of you. Thanks a lot

Comment: Dear https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650, your solution to my answer was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to fit an actual model, or do you want to produce a curved line like in the example image? If it's the latter, you could use "loess", a piecewise linear model, in the geom_smooth() argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used geom_smooth(), but I dont want the line fitted with 'loess'. I want to fit a actual model.